# How to unregister GWT eventbus handlers in a Popup/DialogBox?

Tags: gwt, event-bus

I have a dialog box, which contains a button and a TabLayoutPanel. The button is outside the TabLayoutPanel. Tab contents are separate custom widgets.

The problem: I want to respond to clicks on the button by performing an action inside one of the tab content widgets.

I tried using the GWT EventBus this way:

1. fire an event upon button click
2. add handler for this event inside the tab

But here's the problem: if I close/open the tab multiple times, the event handler will be registered again. And when the button is clicked, the event handler will start multiple times (for every handler registration/however many times the tab was opened).

Since my dialog box doesn't have an activity/place, I cannot use GWT's `Activity.start(... EventBus eventBus)` for automatic activity deregistration.

A possible solution is to manually remember registered `HandlerRegistration`(s) and `.removeHandler()` them when I navigate away from the tab. But this is a rather ugly solution.

Question: Is there a way to unregister events in a dialog box without remembering them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to give a concrete answer without code, but I'd do it like this:

1. Add ClickHandler to the button when the Popup/Dialog gets opened.
2. If this button is clicked, check which tab is the active one and call a specific method on the widget in that tab.
   `getSelectedIndex()` and `getWidget(index)` should be the methods on the TabLayoutPanel to use to determine which widget is the active one.
3. Unregister the clickhandler after the Popup/Dialog got closed.

This way, you have only one Handler to remove what should be the normal way, e.g. with the `onClose()` event of the DialogBox.